How to use Blurhash when the width and height are dynamic?
So im using the react-blurhash package to add placeholders for my images. It expects a width and a height parameter in integers, to define the height and width of the placeholder itself. If i dont know the width and height, lets say it is dependent on the parent ( or as a percentage ) How do i use it then?
Sample Code:
<div className='sm:w-[50%] w-full flex items-center justify-center'>
                <div className="relative w-full h-full">
                    {isLoading && <Blurhash
                        hash="L5IW7%8x3@1G2,Dz.{{}BN0g}u1I"
                        width={"100%"}
                        height={"100%"}
                        resolutionX={32}
                        resolutionY={32}
                        punch={1}
                        className='absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full transition-opacity duration-500 rounded-lg'
                    />}
                    <img src={Rica} alt="Rica" className='rounded-lg lg:h-[500px] relative z-10 transition-opacity duration-500' onLoad={() => { setIsLoading(false) }} />
                </div>
 </div>

As seen above i have tried using "100%" but that doesnt seem to work. Anyone have any ideas?

The react-blurhash package requires the width and height props to be integers, so passing "100%" as a string won't work.
If your image dimensions depend on the parent element's size (like a percentage), you can calculate the dimenions of the parent and pass them as numbers.
Use useRef and useEffect for Parent Dimensions.
const containerRef = useRef(null);
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });


useEffect(() => {
    // Calculate the dimensions of the parent container
    const updateDimensions = () => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            setDimensions({
                width: containerRef.current.offsetWidth, // If required use `.scrollWidth` instead.
                height: containerRef.current.offsetHeight, // and `.scrollHeight`
            });
        }
    };

    updateDimensions();

    // If you want you can remove this, if window resize won't affect the parent dimensions
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateDimensions);
}, []);

return (
    <div
        ref={containerRef} // Considered it's the parent container
        className='sm:w-[50%] w-full flex items-center justify-center'
    >
        <div className="relative w-full h-full">
            {isLoading && <Blurhash
                hash="L5IW7%8x3@1G2,Dz.{{}BN0g}u1I"
                width={dimensions.width}
                height={dimensions.height}
                resolutionX={32}
                resolutionY={32}
                punch={1}
                className='absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full transition-opacity duration-500 rounded-lg'
            />}
            <img src={Rica} alt="Rica" className='rounded-lg lg:h-[500px] relative z-10 transition-opacity duration-500' onLoad={() => { setIsLoading(false) }} />
        </div>
    </div>
)

I hope it solves your issue. If you have any queries, feel free to ask. Happy learning!

my width is known, but my height is auto, what do i do in this case?

In that case we have to use a specific height like height = {100} or 200 or any height which looks good with your  design

that’s not ideal right, cause i don’t want the placeholder and the actual image causing layout shifts

As you said in your question, image height would be height of parent container, and parent container height is auto, then height of the container is dependant on height of the image, but until image is loaded we won't know exact height, in that case define the specific height of the image or container then pass it to Blurhash or just let the layout shifts happen. There's no other way

What if you hide the image when isLoading is true so that it doesn't take up any space in the DOM, and only the placeholder takes up space in DOM. And when image loads the Placeholder is not rendered and the image is block taking up the width and height. Then u can give the placeholder and image same width and height value.
So u won't be using  width={"100%"} height={"100%"} with the placeholder.
Here's is an example:
<div className='sm:w-[50%] w-full flex items-center justify-center'>
    <div className="relative w-full h-full">
       {isLoading && <Blurhash
       hash="L5IW7%8x3@1G2,Dz.{{}BN0g}u1I"
       width={"100%"}
       height={"100%"}
       resolutionX={32}
       resolutionY={32}
       punch={1}
       className='absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full 
       transition-opacity duration-500 rounded-lg'
     />}
     <img src={Rica} 
      alt="Rica"
      className={`rounded-lg lg:h-[500px] relative z-10 
      transition-opacity duration-500 ${isLoading ? "hidden" : "block" }`}  
      onLoad={() => { setIsLoading(false) }} />
   </div>
 </div>


no this wont work, cause the blurhash component still has a non integer height and width, so it doesnt even render

I just added the  width={"100%"}, height={"100%"} just as from your code, u will need to pass the right value for the width and height to the blurhash
